# WCF service host cannot find any service metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm just learning wcf and currently got this far.

**CS File:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace wcfLib
{            
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IfaceService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int wordLen(string word);
    }

    public class StockService : IfaceService
    {
        public int wordLen(string word)
        {
            return word.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I'm trying to run it, it pops an error:

> WCF service host cannot find any service metadata...

Any idea what it could be?

**Config File:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfLib.Service1Behavior" name="wcfLib.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="wcfLib.ser">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/wcfLib/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wcfLib.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You need to show us your **config** file ! Stuff like the metadata exchange are defined in config

Comment: And which URL do you try to connect to in order to get your metadata?? How are you hosting this service - IIS or self-hosting??

Comment: Yoru code and config don't match - your service in code is `wcfLib.StockService` but your <service> tag contains `name=wcfLib.Service1` - those names need to match! Same with the `contract="wcfLib.ser"` attribute on the endpoint - that needs to match namespace+interface name! (`wcfLib.IfaceService`)

Comment: I had the same problem and it was an issue that did not match the names

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to have the following in your config file:

1) a **service behavior** for metadata:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="Metadata"> 
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

2) reference that service behavior in your service's config

```
<service name="wcfLib.StockService" 
         behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">
     ....
</service>
```

*The name value in the service tags in the config file must have the same name as the physical class that is implementing the contract. Remember if the class name changes, make sure to change this value to match.

3) an endpoint for MEX (metadata exchange)

```
<service name="wcfLib.StockService" 
         behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">
     ....

    <endpoint name="mex"
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

With all this in place, things should be just fine! :-)

Comment: i have all of it you mentioned in above post still I get same error (dialog box).

Answer (score 15):

I got this exact same issue and was vigorously going through my configuration and *everything* was inline with the metadata endpoints, etc. The issue? This line:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="wcfLib.Service1Behavior" name="wcfLib.Service1">
```

The `name` value **MUST, MUST** have the name of the physical class that is implementing the contract. I forgot... once again and arbitrarily named it thinking it could be any string. So in the case above the implementing class must be named `Service1`. If the class name changes, make sure to change this value.

This is like WCF 101 stuff and I still get burnt by it even though I have been doing WCF since CTP in Framework 3.0. Blah...

Comment: I forgot about this when following a tutorial that changed the service interface and class names. Using code refactoring to rename would have avoided this.

Answer (score 2):

I had HTTP Activation turned ON. Make sure you have it on.

[image: Ensure HTTP Activation is on]

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create this problem is to simply re-factor your interface name. It certainly changes the instance name across your project but it fails to update the web.config file. To recreate create a new service, rename your interface and whack F5, boom, metadata dialog appears :-) The answer is as above, just remember to alter your web.config file manually.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add a metadata exchange endpoint:

http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94Metadata_Exchange

Answer (score 0):

By default, Visual Studio is going to try to setup a client/test ui for you to toy with your new service.  To do this it needs to be made aware of the structure and methods your service offers.  This is achieved by consuming a definition in the standard WSDL format.  However, WCF won't publish this data by default.

You have to setup a metadataexchange endpoint behavior to acehive.

Either post your config file here and we can assist, or google/stack search for metadataexchange and wsdl in WCF

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my service name was wrong. Using netTcpBinding and mexTcpBinding with httpGetEnabled = False then worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the <system.serviceModel> / <services> config section
ServicesSection services = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/services") as ServicesSection;

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SelfHostedService.Service));

// enumerate over each <service> node
foreach (ServiceElement aService in services.Services)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} / Behavior: {1}", aService.Name, aService.BehaviorConfiguration);

    // enumerate over all endpoints for that service
    foreach (ServiceEndpointElement see in aService.Endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tEndpoint: Address = {0} / Binding = {1} / Contract = {2}", see.Address, see.Binding, see.Contract);
        //host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    }
}

try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Service EndPoints are: ");
    foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", endpoint.Address.ToString(), endpoint.Binding.Name);
    }
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Service is host at ", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine("\n Self Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

If still not work so delete current config file and reCreate it with its default name App.config, this is works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this same error if you are creating your service host programmatically and forget to add the [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] attributes to the interface contract.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but I thought I'd give my 2 cents on the subject since it just happened to me.

I somehow changed my Build Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" for the web service itself. The second I changed it back to "Any CPU", it resolved the problem.