# C# - Using Windows.winmd in WCF Service

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf

I want to use "BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher" in WCF Service

```
public override void StartWathchingAsync()
        {
            BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher BluetoothWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        }
```

But when I create instances of "BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher" I get the error below

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz4Hl.jpg)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))    at
>   MeasuringDeviceService.MeasuringDeviceClasseis.XiaomiMiScale.StartWathchingAsync()
>   at MeasuringDeviceService.DeviceService.GetData(MeasuringDevice
>   measuringDevice) in C:\Users\Programmer\Desktop\Project
>   MahdKodak\MahdKodak\MeasuringDeviceService\DeviceService.svc.cs:line
>   37    at
>   MeasuringDeviceService.DeviceService.GetDataXiaomiMiScale(XiaomiMiScale
>   xiaomiMiScale) in C:\Users\Programmer\Desktop\Project
>   MahdKodak\MahdKodak\MeasuringDeviceService\DeviceService.svc.cs:line
>   25    at SyncInvokeGetDataXiaomiMiScale(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

And when I comment  the code line below, my program work well

```
//BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher BluetoothWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
```

**EDIT :**

This is my code

**Service Code :**

```
public class DeviceService : IDeviceService
    {
        Semaphore DeviceSemaphor = null;
        public DeviceService()
        {
            DeviceSemaphor = new Semaphore(1, 1);
        }
        public XiaomiMiScaleData GetDataXiaomiMiScale(XiaomiMiScale xiaomiMiScale)
        {
            return GetData(xiaomiMiScale) as XiaomiMiScaleData;
        }

        public MeasuringDeviceData GetData(MeasuringDevice measuringDevice)
        {
            try
            {
                measuringDevice.StartWathchingAsync();
                return measuringDevice.LastData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Other Classes :**

```
[DataContract]
    public class MeasuringDevice
    {
        [DataMember]
        public MeasuringDeviceData LastData { get; set; }
        public MeasuringDevice()
        {
        }
        [DataMember]
        public ulong DeviceBluetoothAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual void StartWathchingAsync()
        {

        }
    }

[DataContract]
    public class XiaomiMiScale : MeasuringDevice
    {
        public XiaomiMiScale()
        {
            LastData = new XiaomiMiScaleData();
        }

        public override void StartWathchingAsync()
        {
            BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher BluetoothWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your method has only one line of code that is causing exception, of course your method will work well when you comment the line. Have you checked if the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher constructor requires a constructor parameter? Do you have access to the API or may be post the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either in MeasuringDeviceService.MeasuringDeviceClasseis.XiaomiMiScale.StartWathchingAsync() or somewhere in MeasuringDeviceService.DeviceService.GetData(MeasuringDevice measuringDevice) that's causing an exception to be thrown.

The reason why you see WCF in the stack is because the above code is being executed inside a WCF service and when the error occurs, the exception is being sent back to the client by means of a FaultException.

I don't know your code or system, but my first guess is you need to figure out what DeviceService.GetData() does and how to get it to work in a standalone manner.

EDIT: Try running BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher BluetoothWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher(); call in a standalone method outside the realm of WCF.

When you do so, does it work as expected?  Can you put a breakpoint on your server side and see exactly what exception is being thrown and paste the callstack?

Comment: thank you
I tested in Console Application and it work well
I made a Gif of my problem
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeMhS.gif)

Comment: I don't have access to the source code but you may want to try something like this:
new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active }; watcher.Start();

Comment: Is not resolved
i found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221692/wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-metadata) about metadata
Is it relevant?

Comment: It's not relevant. The problem is in BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher and how it throws an exception in a parameterless public constructor. What you're showing looks like a bug and you should consider reporting it. Make sure you provide a full working repro.